# Allowing (registered) users to create (sub)folder on my domain

Tags: dns, subdomain, customization

I have the following problem and am looking for possible solutions and/or suggestions on how to solve this.

Let's say I have a domain and I'd like a user to register on it first.
If registered, & paid e.g., allow the user to create his own 'page' (once). 
- my.domain.com/**user-1-pagename** 
- my.domain.com/**user-2-pagename**

**What would be the most reliable and secure way to do this?**
**As you would have to give a user write-access**
- Let user create a subfolder under the root of the website(?) & How (security-wise)
- Easier with a Wordpress or Drupal setup to start from?
- ...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It totally depends on what they would want to do with that page afterwards, if you are thinking of creating blog pages for different users then you have these options on WordPress, I'm sure there are tons of other options for many platforms out there:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/profilegrid-user-profiles-groups-and-communities/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/

But if you are thinking of creating real low level sub-folders for your domain, it would need a lot more information about your host and it may need custom coding.

Comment: I wouldn't allow the user to actually 'do' anything with it. Atleast not something they could 'add' themselves. When they got their own 'page', I would just let them choose from some dropdown options to customize their page e.g. set the background-color of their page or show their name or ...

Comment: So you should go with those user profile and group systems in WordPress or any platform that you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieved by [OG Group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) that will allow register and paid user to create OG NODE and path of the OG NODE at per your requirement (my.domain.com/user-1-pagename) using URL alias [Path Auto module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto)